# Is there a way to query WMI without using PowerShell or CIM Studio?

Tags: windows-7, wmi, wmi-query

I'd like to query WMI for WCF service information, but I'd rather not use PowerShell or the CIM Studio.  Any other tools for doing this (command-line is cool too)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemtest.exe

Type `wbemtest` in to a command prompt or the Start Menu to launch this GUI tool.

Edit: Sorry - didn't notice you said command-line specifically. Maybe useful none the less.

Comment: This is perfect!  I had no idea it existed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could try [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx). It works well enough for interactive use, but I prefer to use vbscript for, well, scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VBScript, but I would not recommend it unless you are already quite familiar with it.

Some examples of using WMI via both PowerShell and VBScript can be found [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/site/search?f[0].Type=Tag&f[0].Value=WMI).